# How do I make sums of sumatrixes in MATLAB without cycle?

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I have a large matrix (time x frequency), which I want to reduce partially. I want to sum every 1000 rows (time-samples) together keepinq the frequency information, it is kind of a segmentation.

Is there any way to do it without any cycle in MATLAB?

A smaller example:

```
M=[1 2 3; 2 3 4; 5 8 7; 5 6 7; 1 2 3; 1 2 4];
```

and I want to sum every 2 rows together so, that I get:

```
[3 5 7; 10 14 14; 2 4 7]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and what you want the result to be?

Comment: I have count a spectrogram for a long EEG signal and I want to sum it along the time dimension so I get a weighted spectrum for the signal - but I want to sum every 1000 samples (segmentation), because of the next signal processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a matrix with N rows and M columns and you want to sum every R rows together (where N is divisible by R),

```
>> mat = [1 2 3; 2 3 4; 5 8 7; 5 6 7; 1 2 3; 1 2 4]
mat =
     1     2     3
     2     3     4
     5     8     7
     5     6     7
     1     2     3
     1     2     4

>> [N, M] = size(mat); %=> [6, 3]
>> R = 2;
```

The following will allow you to sum groups of R rows:

```
>> res = reshape(mat, R, [])
res = 
     1     5     1     2     8     2     3     7     3
     2     5     1     3     6     2     4     7     4

>> res = sum(res) 
res =
     3    10     2     5    14     4     7    14     7

>> res = reshape(res, [], M)
res =
     3     5     7
    10    14    14
     2     4     7
```

You can also do everything in one line:

```
>> reshape(sum(reshape(mat, R, [])), [], M)
ans =
     3     5     7
    10    14    14
     2     4     7
```